# Stub ActivatedRoute in Angular 2 tests

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm struggling to figure out how to stub angular's activated route to suite my purposes. In one of my components, I'm using a route snapshot to get a portion of the activated route's url:

```
let activatedPath = this.route.snapshot.children[0].url[0].path;
```

In my tests, I'm getting the error:

```
Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.route.snapshot.children[0].url')​​
```

So I figure I need to stub Activated route:

```
class FakeActivatedRoute {
    // stub detail goes here
}
```

and provide for it in my test:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      declarations: [
        SiteAdminComponent
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useClass: FakeActivatedRoute }
      ]
    })
     .compileComponents();
}));
```

Can anyone offer any guidance as to the stub implementation that would allow me to get to `.snapshot.children[0].url[0].path`? I'm currently getting nowhere quickly :-)

Comment: Search for 'ActivatedRoute' on the [angular testing guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html). There is an example of a stub. However, I'm trying to implement it for myself right now, but I don't know how to set the testParams _before_ the component is created. Maybe we can help each other? :)

Comment: I now also got the _how to inject_-part. It works with `activatedRoute = new ActivatedRouteStub();` within `beforeEach` and `{ provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: activatedRoute }` in the providers.
I don't use the snapshot, so I cannot help you in this particular problem, but I think with this as a starting point it should not be that hard ;)

Comment: Any news on that ? I'm struggling with it too.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to do something like:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      declarations: [
        SiteAdminComponent
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        { 
          provide: ActivatedRoute, 
          useValue: {snapshot: {children: [{url: ['your/path/here']}]}} 
        }
      ]
    })
     .compileComponents();
}));
```

This way you are providing a mocked activatedRoute object which will answer to this exact same hierarchy.